# What does it mean to get a "use of undeclared identifier" error? (Xcode9/Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

In Xcode (Objective-C) I am getting the following error:

```
 "Use of undeclared identifier 'touchesBegan' "
```

The error shows up at the *E* (not in actual code)

What does this mean and what can I do to fix it?

I am using Xcode 9 IOS 11.0 to make a simple game.

I'd be glad to receive any help.

Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { *E*
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

static const NSTimeInterval kHugeTime = 9999.0;
SKNode *ball = [self childNodeWithName:@"ball"];


for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    if([touch locationInNode:ball.parent].x < ball.position.x){
        leftTouches++;
    }}
    else{
        rightTouches++;
}
}

if((leftTouches == 1) && (rightTouches == 0)){
        //Move Ball Left
    SKAction *leftMove = [SKAction moveBy:CGVectorMake(-1.0*kMoveSpeed*kHugeTime,0) duration:(kHugeTime)];
    [ball runAction:leftMove withKey:@"Action"];
}
else if((leftTouches == 0) && (rightTouches == 1)){
        //Move Ball Right
    SKAction *rightMove = [SKAction moveBy:CGVectorMake(1.0*kMoveSpeed*kHugeTime,0) duration:(kHugeTime)];
    [ball runAction:rightMove withKey:@"Action"];
}
else if((leftTouches + rightTouches) > 1){
        //Jump
    SKAction *jumpMove = [SKAction applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0, 2500) duration:0.4];
    [ball runAction:jumpMove withKey:@"Action"];
} 
} @end
```

---

Comment: What file is this in? You show an `@end`. Is there an `@implementation`?

Comment: You also have an extra `}` just before the `else` of the first `if`. Make sure you have matching curly braces and no extras.

Comment: A good tip for Xcode is to type ⌘-a followed by ctrl-i to re-indent everything and then look to see what doesn't line up as it should